# lost value on code behind

Tags: c#, textbox

i work on VSTS 2012 with framework 4.0 on C#.

i set by default enable = false:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox_CP_dest" runat="server"  Width="60px" TabIndex="30" ClientInstanceName="ASPxTextBox_CP_dest" Enable="false">
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" SetFocusOnError="true">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="true" ErrorText="Champ Obligatoire"  />                                                       
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

but when the user click on checkbox:

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox 
    ID="ASPxCheckBox_NewDesti" 
    runat="server" 
    ClientInstanceName="ASPxCheckBox_NewDesti" 
    OnCheckedChanged="Desti_CheckedChanged" 
    Text="Nouveau destinataire" ForeColor="Green" AutoPostBack="false" 
>

</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

then I set it enable=true:

```
protected void Desti_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ASPxCheckBox_NewDesti.Checked)
    {
        ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.Enabled = true;
        ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

         .....
    }
    else
    {
        ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.Enabled = false;
        ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    }
```

but when I click the Save button:

```
protected void ASPxButton_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {           
        string FA_Choisi = ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.Text.Substring(0, 2);
```

I got value ASPxTextBox_CP_dest.Text = empty

I lost the value after postback. Is that because by default enable =false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i lost the value after postback, is that because by default enable
>   =false ?

Most likely that's the reason. The problem with `enable=false` is that it sets the attribute in the html element to `disabled` and any element with disabled state is not submitted in the request.

My workaround for this is to use the `ReadOnly` property instead of disable and perhaps use a special style to give the appearance of a disabled element, such as a light gray background, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASP does not preserve the value of disabled textboxes across postbacks. You should use the `ReadOnly` attribute instead,  like this:

```
ASPxTextBox_CP_destAttributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Alternatively, add a hidden field and use it to store the same value.